# Panel title followed by a dropdown [Indesign scripting]

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign

I am trying to create a panel with a title and followed by a dropdown as the following image:

[image: Final result]

Currently I have the following code, but the dropdown is inside de panel:

```
var w = new Window('palette', "My palette");

var pageSizePanel = w.add('panel', undefined, 'Page Size', {
    borderStyle: 'gray'
});

pageSizePanel.alignment = ["fill", "fill"];

var dropdown = pageSizePanel.add("dropdownlist", undefined, ['1','2']);
dropdown.selection = 1;
```

Which produces this result:

[image: My result]

Anyone can help please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats w? we have no idea whats going on here because we dont know what w is

Comment: I updated my code